# How to get best route from Quickswap (Uniswap v2)?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts

I'm working on an auto trade script in Quickswap. Swap is work correctly but my problem is I would like to know the best route path as show on the website.

I'm using Nodejs to make the script.

[Quickswap route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au9QY.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.